# How to pass function as props from functional parent component to child

Tags: reactjs, react-props

### Parent Component:

```
const initialValue_modalProps = [
    { show: false, response: "" }
  ];
const [modalProps, setModalProps] = useState(initialValue_modalProps)
const passedFunction = () => {
    setModalProps(modalProps => initialValue_modalProps);
  }
..
..
 <div>
        <Modal show={modalProps.show}
          response={modalProps.response}
          passedFunction={passedFunction}></Modal>
 </div>
```

### Child Component:

```
export default function ModalComp(props) {
    const [modalOpen, setmodalOpen] = useState(true);
    console.log('modalOpen', modalOpen);
    if (props.show === false || modalOpen === false) {
        return null;
    }
    return (<Modal isOpen={props.show}>
        <ModalHeader>Deployment Status</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>{props.response}</ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
            <Button onClick={() => {
                setmodalOpen(modalOpen => false);
                props.passedFunction();
            }}>Close</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>)

}
```

Here I want to passedFunction function from Parent to child so that the Child component can execute it to reset the state in parent

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can take this as an reference with live example demo [https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-6fvyx](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-mendeleev-6fvyx)

```
function App() {
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  const handleClick = () => {
   setStatus(prevStatus => !prevStatus);
  };
  const handleChange = e => {
   setText(e.target.value);
  };


  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Open photo entry dialog</button>
      <ChildComponent
        isOpen={status}
        text={text}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
    </>
  );
}

const ChildComponent = ({ isOpen, text, handleChange, handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {isOpen && (
        <Model
          status={isOpen}
          handleClick={handleClick}
          text={text}
          handleChange={handleChange}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: @Vahid Akhtar The way you are setting the states is ugly. Why don't you use `setState` and `setText` if you're targeting the Hook API?

Comment: how would you approach this if handleClick was in a component class called 'WorldMap'?  I've tried WorldMap.handleClick, ()=>WorldMap.handleClick but no joy. Thanks. D.

Answer (score 7):

You need to remove the parentheses behind `passedFunction`, because otherwise you are executing the function first and passing the result to the child afterwards. Pass your function as it is via `passedFunction={passedFunction}`.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {

  const initialModalProps = { ... };
  const [modalProps, setModalProps] = useState(initialModalProps);

  const passedFunction = () => {
    setModalProps(initialModalProps);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        show={modalProps.show}
        response={modalProps.response}
        passedFunction={passedFunction} />
    </div>
  );

};
```

Comment: Well, you are using the setter of your state `setModalProps` in a wrong way. You set it to be a function. Try `setModalProps(initialValue_modalProps)`.

Comment: Though I have changed to your syntax. but I checked it twice. Both are working.

Answer (score 4):

Changed the child component to this. and its working

```
export default function ModalComp(props) {
    //const [modalOpen, setmodalOpen] = useState(true);
    if (props.show === false) {
        return null;
    }
    return (<Modal isOpen={props.show}>
        <ModalHeader>Deployment Status</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>{props.response}</ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
            <Button onClick={props.passedFunction}>Close</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>)
```